# OCaml and creating a list of lists

Tags: function, logic, ocaml

I am currently trying to make use functions to create:

```
0  V12 V13 V14
V21 0  V23 V24
V31 V32 0  V34
V41 V42 V43 0
```

A way that I found to do this was to use theses equations:

```
(2*V1 - 1)*(2*V2-1) = for spot V(1,2) in the Matrix
(2*V1 - 1)*(2*V3-1) = for spot V(1,3) in the Matrix
etc
```

Thus far I have:

```
let singleState state = 
if state = 0.0 then 0.0
else
    ((2.0 *. state) -. 1.0);;


let rec matrixState v = 
match v with
| [] -> []
| hd :: [] -> v
| hd :: (nx :: _ as tl) ->
    singleState hd *. singleState nx :: matrixState tl;;
```

My results come out to be:

```
float list = [-3.; -3.; -3.; -1.]
```

When they should be a list of lists that look as follows:

```
0 -1 1 -1
-1 0 -1 1
1 -1 0 -1
-1 1 -1 0
```

So instead of it making list of lists it is making just one list. I also have trouble figuring out how to make the diagonals 0.

The signatures should look like:

```
val singleState : float list -> float list list = <fun>
val matrixState : float list list -> float list list = <fun>
```

and I am getting

```
val singleState : float -> float = <fun>
val matrixState : float list -> float list = <fun>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The language you are using is written “OCaml” with a capital O and a capital C. http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/index.en.html

Answer (score 0):

With some fixing up, your function would make one row of the result. Then you could call it once for each row you need. A good way to do the repeated calling might be with `List.map`.

Assuming this is mostly a learning exercise, it might be good to first make a matrix like this:

```
V11 V12 V13 V14
V21 V22 V23 V24
V31 V32 V33 V34
V41 V42 V43 V44
```

I think this will be a lot easier to calculate.

Then you can replace the diagonal with zeroes. Here's some code that would replace the diagonal:

```
let replnth r n l =
    List.mapi (fun i x -> if i = n then r else x) l

let zerorow row (n, res) =
    (n - 1, replnth 0.0 n row :: res)

let zerodiag m =
    let (_, res) = List.fold_right zerorow m (List.length m - 1, []) in
    res
```

Comment: Ah yes it is an exercise but it says not to use list. functions in it which would make it rather difficult

Comment: If it's an exercise I wouldn't want to code it for you anyway :-) You can open these functions out using explicit recursion. Or you can write your own versions of the list functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to go with an array for your work.

A nice function to use is then `Array.init`, it works like so,

```
# Array.init 5 (fun x -> x);;  
- : int array = [|0; 1; 2; 3; 4|]
```

We note that **5** play the role of the size of our Array.

But as you want a matrix we need to build an Array of Array which is achieve with two call of `Array.init`, the last one nested into the first one,

```
# Array.init 3 (fun row -> Array.init 3 (fun col -> row+col));;
- : int array array = [|[|0; 1; 2|]; [|1; 2; 3|]; [|2; 3; 4|]|]
```

Note, I've called my variable **row**  and **col** to denote the fact that they correspond to the row index and column index of our matrix.

Last, as your formula use a vector of reference **V** holding value **[|V1;V2;V3;V4|]**, we need to create one and incorporate call to it into our *matrix builder*, (The value hold on the cell n of an array `tab` is accessed like so `tab.(n-1)`)

Which finally lead us to the working example,

```
let vect = [|1;2;3;4|] 

let built_matrix = 
  Array.init 4 (fun row -> 
    Array.init 4 (fun col -> 
      if col=row then 0
      else vect.(row)+vect.(col)))
```

Of course you'll have to adapt it to your convenience in order to match this piece of code according to your requirement.

A side note about syntax,
Repeating Array each time can be avoid using some nice feature of OCaml.
We can locally open a module like so,

```
let built_matrix = 
 let open Array in 
   init 4 (fun row -> 
     init 4 (fun col -> 
       if col=row then 0
       else vect.(row)+vect.(col)))
```

Even shorter, `let open Array in ...` can be write as `Array.(...)`, Below a chunk of code interpreted under the excellent **utop** to illustrate it (and I going to profit of this opportunity to incorporate a conversion of our matrix to a list of list.)

```
utop # 
Array.(
  to_list 
  @@ map to_list 
  @@ init 4 (fun r -> 
     init 4 (fun c -> 
       if r = c then 0 
       else vect.(r)+ vect.(c))))
;;
- : int list list = [[0; 3; 4; 5]; [3; 0; 5; 6]; [4; 5; 0; 7]; [5; 6; 7; 0]]
```

I hope it helps